# Show new lines (\n) of type string when displaying tables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have a table in my rails project, which contains a column of type string. One of the entries for this column is "one\ntwo". When I try to display the table, that entry is displayed as "one two". I serialized the entry, so I tried displaying an inspected version as well, which displayed "one\ntwo". Is there any way to display that entry as following?

one

two

Comment: s.gsub(/\n/, '<br>') try this, and play with sanitize or maybe html_safe. I can be wrong

Comment: Awesome! That made it work! If you repost your comment as an answer, I will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s.gsub(/\n/, '<br>')` try this, and play with sanitize or maybe html_safe